один и тот же код не работает aiogram
у меня есть бот для регистрации и я добавил в нём команду бана. Хендлеры и функции для этой команды я скопировал с одного из моих прошлых проектов, где структура кода такая же, там команда идеально работает, а в моём новом боте, бот переходит на следующий state, но хэндлер для этого  стейта не срабатывает. Ниже приведу код
@dp.message_handler(commands=['ban'], state=None)
async def check_admin(message:types.message, state:FSMContext):
    member = await bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)

    if isinstance(member, ChatMemberOwner):
        await message.answer("Please type the name of the person you want to ban.")
        await Ban.nickname_ask.set()
    else:
        await message.answer("You are not allowed to use this command.")

 @dp.message_handler(state=Ban.nickname_ask)
 async def name_ask(message:types.message, state:FSMContext):

 async with state.proxy() as data:
     data['nickname'] = message.text
 await Ban.ban_list_add.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Ban.ban_list_add)
async def list_add(message:types.message, state:FSMContext):
async with state.proxy() as data:
    await message.answer(f"User banned successfully: @{data['nickname']}")
    await add.add_name(data['nickname'])

сори, в некоторых местах таба нет, криво вставил
короче, бот переходит в Ban.nickname_ask(), но хэндлер для него не срабатывает
если надо будет полный код, пишите
